# How to describe a parent with a lenient approach to parenting?

Tags: adjectives

I'm trying to describe my character as a parent who has a fairly 'hands-off' approach to raising his children. He is a single man who inherited a young boy and girl after the death of a family friend, and whose job prevents him from being too heavily involved in their day-to-day activities. But, he loves them, is always there for them when they need him, and cares very deeply for their moral upbringing. He just doesn't really know what he's doing.

So... What is the word for my character's 'hands-off', make-it-up-as-you-go-along style of parenting?

P.S. This character, if this helps, is very similar in moral code and behavior to Atticus Finch.

Comment: Your question body (no flowery affectionate displays and/or Atticus Finch) differs from your title (lenient)  which is it?

Comment: Sorry... I realized partway through that I had two questions. :) "lenient" is the main thing that I'm wondering about... I don't feel like its the right word for what I'm trying to say.

Comment: How about ***taciturn***?

Comment: Yes, I think that works. Thank you! Also: is there a word to describe a parent who doesn't really know what he's doing? This character might be seen as 'lenient' because he's kind of making it up as he goes along... might there be a better adjective for that?

Comment: You are not going to get for one word hands-off, make it up as he goes along, and there when he really has to be.   The way you describe him, I'd say he is experimental, with a good sense of priorities.

Comment: There’s ***laissez-faire***

Comment: @Tom22 - or ***permissive***

Comment: @Jim  yeah.. I knew it wasn't quite right..

Comment: Indulgent; casual.

Comment: **Diffident** gets close to both halves of your request.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  "He just doesn't really know what he's doing": bumbling.  "A fairly 'hands-off' approach to raising his children": benign neglect.

Comment: The kids are *feral*.

Comment: clueless parenting to describe a parent who doesn't really know what he's doing. Clueless leniency could be used.

Answer (score -1):

Title alone seems to call for the harshness of Lax.

Body text suggests...

amateur, with-the-band, parent-in-training, student of parenting, modern parent, adopted parent, and my favorite:  pit crew

Best Wishes